# How to get a data member default value using Source Generator?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, c#-9.0, sourcegenerators

About the C# 9 new feature named [Source Generator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/), how to get a property default value?

For example:

```cs
class MyClass
{
    public int MyValue { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

How to get the `1` defined at compile time?

Comment: I think you need to declare the variable as `const` then only you will get value at compile time

Comment: Value initialization (assignment) happens on runtime only. Hence, you need to run the program to get the assigned value.

Comment: Found: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/C-Source-Generators | [Source Generators Cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md)

Answer (score 1):

The value is not present at compile time, however, you can still get the syntax from the source code during compilation.

If you're using symbols, once you find the `IPropertySymbol`, you need to get the syntax node from it via `DeclaringSyntaxReferences` then `GetSyntax()`. The property symbol doesn't have the "runtime" value abstracted.

The syntax node you're looking for is `PropertyDeclarationSyntax`, there you get the `Initializer` and its `Value`, which is the `ExpressionSyntax`.

For fields, you need the `VariableDeclaratorSyntax`.

Example with `ISymbol`:

```
var equalsSyntax = symbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences[0].GetSyntax() switch
{
    PropertyDeclarationSyntax property => property.Initializer,
    VariableDeclaratorSyntax variable => variable.Initializer,
    _ => throw new Exception("Unknown declaration syntax")
};

// If the property/field has an initializer
if (equalsSyntax is not null)
{
    var valueAsStr = equalsSyntax.Value.ToString();
}
```